# VBScript - Create file with user defined name and extension via cmd.exe

Tags: file, vbscript, cmd, export

Apologies for lack of indentations. The problem is twofold and specific to the last line of the code. 
Firstly I can't seem to get %username% to work in its context... and secondly the ". & ext". I have tried typing the full destination folder address, to no avail; and have tried adding enveloping quotes for the dot extension, again to no avail... I have some experience with CMD but little with VBS... any help is appreciated!

```
dim name, app, ext

do
name = inputbox ("Please enter file name", "Make File")
if name = "" then
wscript.quit ()
end if
loop until name <> ""

do while (ext = "")
app = inputbox ("Please enter related application", "Make File")
if app = "" then
wscript.quit ()
elseif lcase(app) = "notepad" then
ext = "txt"
elseif lcase(app) = "word" then 
ext = "doc"
elseif lcase(app) = "excel" then
ext = "xml"
elseif lcase(app) = "powerpoint" then
ext = "ppt"
else
msgbox("Application not recognised")
end if
loop

msgbox "File created in desktop folder"

set objshell = createobject("wscript.shell")
objshell.run "cmd /c echo. > c:\Users\%username%\Desktop\" & name . & ext
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, in your example, you are missing some quotes around the fullstop in the last line of your code, but I suspect this is just a typo, because it still probably wouldn't work. You'd need to double quote it like this:

```
objshell.run "cmd /c echo. > ""c:\Users\%username%\Desktop\" & name &"." & ext & """"
```

Given that the desktop folder is a "special" folder, it's probably best if you didn't try to enumerate the folder in the way you are trying to here - in some environments, the user profile is remapped somewhere else.

Instead, you could modify the last few lines of your code like this:

```
msgbox "File created in desktop folder"
set objshell = createobject("wscript.shell")
desktopFolder = objShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")                    ' This will get you the desktop folder location...

objshell.run "cmd /c echo. > """& desktopfolder & "\" & name & "." & ext & """"     ' This is messy, but it will likely work.
```

Alternatively, you could replace your whole code with the following example. Instead of using confusing elseif code, you could use a case statement and also I'm not sure if you're aware, but if you only have a single condition on an IF statement, you can key them in on the same line (see example below).

In addition, given you're already in VBS, you may as well create the file using a vb command, rather than shelling out to run a CMD.... so instead of using the cmd /c echo line, you could just use something like this:

```
 Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(desktopfolder & "\" & Name & "." & Ext,True)
```

Anyway, here's another version of the script that should work for you.
Have a nice day ! :)

---

**REVISED VERSION**

```
Option Explicit                     
Dim Name, App, Ext
Dim objShell, objFSO, desktopFolder, objFile

Do
   Name = inputbox ("Please enter file name", "Make File")
   if Name = "" Then Wscript.Quit ()
Loop until Name <> ""

Do 
   App = inputbox ("Please enter related application", "Make File") 
   If App = "" Then Wscript.Quit ()
   Select Case (LCase(App))
   Case "notepad"
      Ext = "txt"
   Case "word"
      Ext = "doc"
   Case "excel"
      Ext = "xml"
   Case "powerpoint"
      Ext = "ppt"
   Case else    
      msgbox("Application not recognised")
      App = ""
   End Select
Loop Until App <> ""

set objShell = Createobject("wscript.shell")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
desktopFolder = objShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")

Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(desktopfolder & "\" & Name & "." & Ext,True)
objFile.Close

msgbox "File created in desktop folder"
```

Comment: Wow! ...thank you very much for the detailed feed back. :D I was aware of the "case" alternative to my code, but not the tie-in with the single if condition... I tried your first suggestion to my code regarding the desktop folder, unfortunately it still doesn't work that way... I have been trying many different arrangements but with no joy. Nevertheless I am very grateful for your VB alternative, which is perfect, since as you say it keeps the code strictly VB. I appreciate your time and effort. Thanks again, and a nice day/night to you too! :D

Comment: Have you tried the "revised suggestions"? I've tested here and it seems to be working..?

Comment: I tried the "messy" modification, but it didn't work, the script ran but no file was created... It's of little concern to me now, I much prefer your pure VB method.

Comment: Hang on... update on my last comment, I've just found the files, they've been created in my C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\ folder with desktop concatenated to the name variable... hmmm

Comment: AHA! I see why it's not working (it's missing a slash)... Sorry about that. My edit didn't save.. ...

Comment: Anyway - as you say, the vb way works.. It was bugging me why the other one wasn't working.. now it is. :) Catch ya round! :)